# Python | Работа с NFC

Tags: python, nfc

Хочу написать своё собственное приложение для бесконтактной оплаты и хранения скидочных карт. С картами понятно, можно использовать фотографии. Возможно ли написать Android приложение на Python, и существует ли библиотека для работы с модулем NFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть модуль `nfcpy`.
Страница PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/nfcpy/
Документация: https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Исходный код: https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy

Comment: Ещё вопрос. Терминалы будут принимать приложение?

Comment: @Alexander_K не знаю